# Eclipse: auto-terminating(java)

Tags: java, eclipse

When I write a code in java in Eclipse and run it for second time, the first process is still running. When I, for example, write an infinite loop with some prints, run it once and then again, it is printing from both running, from the first and second. Plus, Eclipse is getting slow. Is there a way to auto-terminate the first process when re-run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can right click on the entry in the Debug-View and choose "Terminate and Relaunch", that is the closest I got to what you would like to have as it will first stop the currently running instance and then start a new one with the same settings.

Other from that you would probably implement something on your own, i.e. a socket where the instance listens and where the new one sends a shutdown command before it fully starts up.

Comment: Terminate and Relaunch is good, I set a shortcut and it is fine! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your program doesn't exit. You can quit the process with the little red square in the upper right corner of the console view.

Comment: Thanks. Some ways to make it automatic? I am writing  a game loop without exit so far. I think it would be more comfortable when it happens with re-run and I don't have to always click on that button.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:**

Go to **Window -> Show View -> Debug**, choose your program and terminate it.

**Long explanation:**

By the description of your problem, you are probably using a framework that uses threads (Are you using Swing in your game?). You can also see the running threads in the debug view.

The JVM will not end the process until all user threads are finished.

If you are using Swing you can use [JFrame setDefaultCloseOperation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29) to change the default behavior of the Window close.

Or you can terminate the JVM process by using [System.exit(0)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29).

Answer (score 1):

The consensus seems to be that this is impossible. Coming from a scripting background, I'm used to doing a lot of manual tests and I like compiling the program with nearly every change.

The following class (Bomber) make System.exit(0) after 10 minutes.  Just toss a Bomb object in Main, `Bomber daBomb = new Bomber();` and trigger `daBomb.reset();` to reset the timer.  Once processes collect like flies on a windowsill, you click the double X ([image: the "remove all terminated launches" button]) in the console tab bar to close the consoles of *all* dead processes.

```
public class Bomber {

Bomb bomb = new Bomb();

public Bomber() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread thread = new Thread(bomb);
    thread.start();
}

public void reset() {
    bomb.reset();
}

//kill because someone cut the redwire!
public void redWire() { 
    bomb.timer = 1000;
}

//Defuses bomb
public void greenWire() {
    reset();
    bomb.greenWire=false;
}

public class Bomb implements Runnable {

    public int timer;
    public boolean greenWire;

    public Bomb() {
        reset();
        greenWire=true;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (timer > 1) {
                Thread.sleep(1000L);
                timer = timer - 1000;
                 //System.out.println(timer);
            }
            if (greenWire) {
                System.exit(0); // kill, because no-one cut the green wire.
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException iex) {
        }
    }

    public void reset() {
        timer = 3000000; // five minutes
        // timer = 5000; // Five seconds
    }

}
}
```

How elaborately you want to incorporate the Bomber functionality is up to you.  I created a function for Main.  Note that the following may not work perfectly, as I just ripped out a bunch of non-core code and didn't test to make sure it still worked.

```
    public static void startUp() throws InterruptedException {
    Bomber daBomb = new Bomber();
    String input = "";

    Interpreter console = new Interpreter();
    while (!input.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {

        daBomb.reset();
        input = terminal.next().toLowerCase();
    }
    daBomb.redWire();
}
```

Comment: A scripting background and often re-run is also my case. Interesting solution. I'll try. Thanks