# eclipse stop popup "Web launch already running"

Tags: eclipse

I am developing in PHP with Xdebug and for some reason every now and then the debug session stops working, so i click again the debug button but it gives me this error all the time "**Web launch already running**", so i have to go to Debug Perspective and click "**Terminate and Relaunch**".

Is there a way to make eclipse automatically terminate and relaunch or launch two sessions or don't show this popup, for 2 years this popup has been bugging me xD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in response to questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8609778/85950) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385313/restarting-an-app-in-eclipse), the best current solution appears to be binding "Terminate and Relaunch" to a keyboard shortcut.

Not automatic, but at least a lot less clicking around.

Comment: used http://stackoverflow.com/a/7101287/579646 in the end, nothing to do be done about it

Answer (score 2):

I have taken care of pesky popups in Eclipse with AutoHotkey script which have worked very well. I could create an AutoHotkey script which sends specific keystrokes automatically every time there is a specific pop-up.

So the flow I had in mind was as follows : 
You click on the debug button -> The Error popup appears and as soon as that happens the AutoHotKey script kicks in and automatically does what you have to do manually.

If you think that might be worth looking into then we can talk more in a Chat session somewhere. I would need some information about the Pop up using the AU3_Spy.exe bundled with the AutoHotkey [Installer](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Searching on Google, I found that many people have the same problem.

Bellow are some links that help you, I think:

- https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/questions/123-definitive-installation-guide-for-php-debugging-on-linuxubuntu
- A good article: http://www.latenightpc.com/blog/archives/2008/05/24/a-complete-lamp-development-environment-xampp-eclipse-pdt-and-xdebug
- See this, too: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/57493/
- Take a look here, too: [Getting error in XDEBUG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438910/getting-error-in-xdebug)

So, read and try, read and try.